# Pandas: multiplying a column by another if it is the same year

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, one is sampled monthly, the other is sampled yearly.

I want to multiply the values from a column in the monthly dataframe by the value from a column in the yearly dataframe if it is the same year. How can I do that?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]}, index=['2018 - 01', '2018 - 02', '2018 - 03', '2019 - 01', '2019 - 02'])
df1

           column1
2018 - 01        1
2018 - 02        1
2018 - 03        1
2019 - 01        2
2019 - 02        2

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'columnX' : [2, 3]}, index=['2018', '2019'])     
df2

      columnX
2018        2
2019        3
```

Expected result:

```
               column1
2018 - 01            2
2018 - 02            2
2018 - 03            2
2019 - 01            6
2019 - 02            6
```

Comment: This time I had to sit and toil to fix your question. Please don't leave that work to someone else, not everyone is as forgiving as I am. In future, make sure your questions are self-contained with enough _code_ or textual data to copy and paste to work with. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You may perform index-aligned multiplication with DataFrames `df1` and `df2`.

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
df1['new'] = df1.set_index(df1.index.str.split(r'\s*-').str[0]).mul(df2).values

df1
           column1  new
2018 - 01        1    2
2018 - 02        1    2
2018 - 03        1    2
2019 - 01        2    6
2019 - 02        2    6
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thank you very much for your help! Sorry for the incomplete example! I have tried your code and it works well. However I tried to adapt it for datetime index and could not get it to work.   `df1['new'] = df1.set_index(df1.index.year).mul(df2.set_index(df2.index.year)).values` Any idea on how to do it with date time index?

Comment: @Peslier53 It's been a while. Why don't you open a fresh question with your updated question? If one of these answers were useful, you can mark them accepted as having solved your initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple index , then do `mul`(multiple)

```
df1['mul']=df1.set_index(df1.index.str[:4],append=True).mul(df2.columnX,level=1,axis=0).values
df1
Out[123]: 
           column1  mul
2018 - 01        1    2
2018 - 02        1    2
2018 - 03        1    2
2019 - 01        2    6
2019 - 02        2    6
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the year from `df1` and map it via `df2['columnX']`.

```
df1['column1'] *= df1.index.str.split(' - ').str[0].map(df2['columnX'].get)
```

Result:

```
print(df1)

           column1
2018 - 01        2
2018 - 02        2
2018 - 03        2
2019 - 01        6
2019 - 02        6
```